# hadoop and graph theory

Tags: graph, hadoop, parallel-processing, hama

Has anyone ever implemented algorithms on the centrality, betweenness centrality, closeness centrality etc in Hadoop  Giraph or Hama? Or rather, has anyone ever parallelized the calculation of metrics on oriented weighted graphs?

I found a thesis of the University of Uppsala

> Social Network Analysis Utilizing  Big Data Technology

nothing more

Comment: It might be fruitful to even post this over user-groups of hama and giraph as u will get good responses over there as compared to SO

Comment: I've implemented Eigenvector Centrality algorithms myself in Hadoop, albeit not using Giraph or Hama. Unfortunately, I can't really show you any examples as it is company confidential code now, but it is entirely feasible.